# Is there a way AWS Cognito tells whenever a user's session expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am currently using Cognito Managed Pool. My use case is whenever a user's session expires I want to get a notification or a Lamda to be triggered. Is there a way to do this through an Cognito Triggers or Cognito Sync.

Comment: The no way to do this currently on Cognito. What is use case if I may ask? Technically user can have many tokens issued and the fact that one of them expired does not mean anything. Unless you build a custom system to track all tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) . The lambda will run whenever it issues an identity token. You can take the token and put some data into a database (say dynamodb). You would then need to run another lambda on a frequent basis (say every minute) to check for expired tokens, and send a SNS if a token is expired. Bear in mind the user might have refreshed tokens, so you would probably want to make the userid the partition key, such that if tokens are refreshed, it overwrites the old one and you don't get a notification.